# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyGenerator AES implementation not found

Tags: android, aes

I'm getting the following exception (so far only Android 4.0.4):

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyGenerator AES implementation not found
       at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.notFound(Engine.java:177)
       at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:151)
       at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyGenerator.java:103)
```

This is my code:

```
 KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
 keyGen.init(128);
 SecretKey confidentialityKey = keyGen.generateKey();
```

Is 128 AES not supported on some versions of Android?

Comment: Use BouncyCastle (Provider).

Comment: Or better, SpongyCastle.

Comment: are these implemented in Android sdk enviromnent? Any guide how to implement them?

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need a key factory for AES in Java. AES keys consist simply of random bytes. So that means you can perform the following:

```
SecureRandom rng = new SecureRandom();

byte[] aesKeyData = new byte[128 / Byte.SIZE];
rng.nextBytes(aesKeyData);
SecretKey aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(aesKeyData, "AES");

// just to show it works
Cipher aesCBC = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
byte[] iv = new byte[aesCBC.getBlockSize()];
rng.nextBytes(iv);
aesCBC.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
```

The only problem is that you cannot generate an AES key on a hardware device this way; for that you would need a `KeyFactory`.

---

If you have a library that requires a key generator then you are best off installing Bouncy Castle or - to avoid naming conflicts - Spongy Castle.

Comment: Because of symmetry with other ciphers and to support hardware devices, there really *should* be an AES `SecretKeyFactory` though.